# Images not displayed in AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I m trying to experiment with AWS serverless and amplify using the following link: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/module-1/

In the first part of the exercise, in the AWS amplify I could deploy the app but Amplify is not displaying any images. I tried the solution posted at https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/2849 by editing rewrite rules. But it didn't help.

Any thoughts? Thanks.